# Cannot set LinkLocalAddressBehavior to LinkLocalAlwaysOff

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to set `LinkLocalAddressBehavior` for an interface to `LinkLocalAlwaysOff` by using [SetIpInterfaceEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/netioapi/nf-netioapi-setipinterfaceentry) function, but I'm always getting `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`. When I set `LinkLocalAddressBehavior` to `LinkLocalDelayed`, `SetIpInterfaceEntry` executes without problem.

I haven't found anything that may help with this problem at MSDN ([SetIpInterfaceEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/netioapi/nf-netioapi-setipinterfaceentry), [MIB_IPINTERFACE_ROW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/netioapi/ns-netioapi-_mib_ipinterface_row) or [NL_LINK_LOCAL_ADDRESS_BEHAVIOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/nldef/ne-nldef-_nl_link_local_address_behavior)).

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**: Code sample:

```
// Initialize MIB_IPINTERFACE_ROW with actual InterfaceLuid:
auto row = MIB_IPINTERFACE_ROW{ AF_INET, 1689399632855040 };

// GetIpInterfaceEntry succeeds
auto result = GetIpInterfaceEntry(&row);

// Setting the value:
row.LinkLocalAddressBehavior = LinkLocalAlwaysOff;

// SetIpInterfaceEntry fails with ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER:
result = SetIpInterfaceEntry(&row);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3927):

> The assignment of an IPv4 Link-Local address on an interface is based
> solely on the state of the interface, and is independent of any other
> protocols such as DHCP. A host MUST NOT alter its behavior and use of
> other protocols such as DHCP because the host has assigned an IPv4
> Link-Local address to an interface.

So we are not able to change its behavior, when it is enabled. the `LinkLocalDelayed` succeed because the original status was `LinkLocalDelayed`.

For IPv6, I found an answer on [msdn](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/73657d0a-79fe-45de-8c0a-e1db361bc3b4/howto-disable-link-local-ipv6-address?forum=windowsserver2008r2networking). Seem like they have some similar behaviors. If one has been enable, then it will not be able to disabled.